# How to get the bound of a summation changed from $e^x$?

Tags: summation, upper-lower-bounds, exponential-sum

I meet a problem with calculating
$$
\frac{e^{-|\alpha|^2}}{\sum A_k^2}\left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A_k \frac{(-\alpha)^k}{\sqrt{k!}}\right|^2\,.
$$
Only I know is the constrain that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A_k \frac{\alpha^k}{\sqrt{k!}}=0$.

How to get the result, or the upper and lower bound?

(so sorry that I missed the square roof of $k!$)

Comment: What is $A_k$  ?

Comment: You can get an upper bound by using 
[Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality). The lower bound is, of course, $0$ (for $\alpha=0$)

Comment: $A_k$ is a set of parameters satisfying the constrain. Generally, it's a complex number.

Comment: Finally, I'm so sorry that I do the wrong derivation that this problem may be meaningless. So should I delete this Question?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the purpose of that constraint is to just prove that the series converges, as if that sequence converges, that alternating sequence does too.

Using @Dmitry's hint, you can get a decent upper bound with Cauchy-Schwartz:

$|U*V|^2 \le U^2 * V^2 $, which with $\sum U_k * V_k \le \sum U_k \sum V_k$ implies that $\sum |U * V|^2 = |\sum U_k|^2|\sum V_k|^2$
$$
\frac{e^{-|\alpha|^2}}{\sum A_k^2}\left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A_k \frac{(-\alpha)^k}{k!}\right|^2 \le \frac{e^{-|\alpha|^2}}{\sum A_k^2}\left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A_k \right|^2 \left| \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-\alpha)^k}{k!}\right|^2
$$

$$
\le \frac{e^{-|\alpha|^2}}{\sum A_k^2}(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A_k^2) \left| \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-\alpha)^k}{k!}\right|^2
$$

$$
= e^{-|\alpha|^2} \left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-\alpha)^k}{k!}\right|^2
$$

$$
= e^{-|\alpha|^2} (e^{-\alpha})^2
$$

$$
= e^{-|\alpha|^2 - 2\alpha}
$$

The simplest lower bound would be zero. This could occur for $\alpha = 0$ or specific $A$'s, whether it makes $lim_{n->\infty} \sum A_k^2 = \infty$ or the alternating sequence sum is pushed to zero somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is it possible to know the lower bound for a specific $\alpha$?

Comment: After I corrected my question, using Cauchy-Schwartz, the result seems like $\leq e^0=1$, did I make a mistake?
This is actually a calculation for the probability, this upper bound seems meaningless.